# Do there exist odd primes $p,q$ with $2^{pq}+1\equiv(2^p+1)^q\pmod{\frac{3^p-1}2}$ and vice versa?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

This question is inspired by my partial answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462631/congruence-satisfied-by-primes-and-only-by-primes/2464634#2464634) question. I would like to know whether there exist any odd primes $p,q$ such that:
$$2^{pq}+1\equiv(2^p+1)^q\pmod{\frac{3^p-1}2}$$
$$2^{pq}+1\equiv (2^q+1)^p\pmod{\frac{3^q-1}{2}}$$
So far, I've found no examples with $p,q\le 100$.

Comment: According to my calculation, there is no solution with $3\le p\le q\le 1\ 000$