# Congruence satisfied by primes and only by primes II

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

This question is closely related to: [Congruence satisfied by primes and only by primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2462631/15660)

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample for the following claim :

> Let n be a natural number greater than two and $n \neq 4$ . Then n is prime if and only if
>
> $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(3^k-2\right) \equiv 
> 2^n-1 \pmod{\frac{3^n-1}{2}}$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLszU2tObKTNPwzU_RKCgCEtm2hjp5uoY6xnHZukaaOhrGcUCepr6Rpq2tEYipU1CUmVeioQSkclOVNGHc5PzcgvzizBKgkKY1ACHJGVw=&lang=gp) .

I was searching for a counterexample using the following two PARI/GP programs :

```
CE1(n1,n2)=
{
forcomposite(n=n1,n2,
if(Mod(prod(k=1,n-1,3^k-2),(3^n-1)/2)==2^n-1,print("n="n)))
}
CE2(n1,n2)=
{
forprime(n=n1,n2,
if(!(Mod(prod(k=1,n-1,3^k-2),(3^n-1)/2)==2^n-1),print("n="n)))
}
```

Comment: No counterexample upto $n=10^4$

Comment: If $n$ is prime, $N=\frac{3^n-1}{2}$ is square-free and odd $=\prod_j p_j$, then $n = ord(3 \bmod N)$, let $r_j = order(3 \bmod p_j)$, $r_j \ne 1$ and $r_j |n$ so $r_j = n$,
 then $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (3^k-2) \equiv  (-1)^{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^n (2-3^k) \equiv 2^n-1 \bmod p_j$, since this is true for every $p_j$ then $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (3^k-2) \equiv 2^n-1 \bmod N$. If $n$ is not prime it becomes $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (3^k-2) \equiv (2^{r_j}-1)^{n/r_j} \bmod p_j$ so $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (3^k-2) \equiv \sum_j \frac{N}{p_j}b_j (2^{r_j}-1)^{n/r_j} \bmod N$ where $ \frac{N}{p_j} b_j\equiv 1 \bmod p_j$

Comment: How did you motivate/come up with this congruence?

Comment: @YiFan This claim was inspired by [Vantieghems theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantieghems_theorem)

Comment: parforprime and Mod each term of the product may help.